# ¿Cómo demostrar mediante la lógica de Hoare la correctitud de un programa con un ciclo while?

Tags: algoritmos, lógica, teoría

Cómo puedo demostrar mediante la [lógica de Hoare](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_de_Hoare) la correctitud de un programa que tenga un ciclo `while`. Sería fascinante que lo desarrollen con un ejemplo cualquiera, igual mi problema a resolver es:

> Precondición={n>0}

```
cont := n;
sum := 0;
while cont <> 0 do:
    sum := sum + cont;
    cont := cont-1;
endwhile
```

> Poscondición={sum=1+2+...+n}

No es necesario que desarrollen este ejemplo solo necesito entender el procedimiento pues no tengo ningún ejemplo práctico. Muchas Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Quizás esto te ayude amigo [Léelo](http://www.lcc.uma.es/~jmmb/ttaadd/ttaadd2-2.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta fue la respuesta que recibí en [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197107/how-to-demonstrate-the-correctness-of-a-program-with-a-while-cycle-using-hoares) disculpa si encuentran defectuosa la traducción, o si encuentran algunos link en inglés:

Lógica de Hoare ["while" reglas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic#While_rule) deben de ser aplicadas:

> Si un comando `S` satisface una tripla de Hoare de la forma `{P ∧ B} S {P}`, entonces el comando `while B do S` satisfisface `{P} while B do S {P ∧ ¬B}`.

Esta es la única técnica que debe de ser aplicada para probar la postcondición de un ciclo `while` en la lógica de Hoare. La condición `B` y el cuerpo de `S` están dado en el código, aunque `P` puede ser cualquier condición que elijas siempre que `{P ∧ B} S {P}` se cumpla.

Este triple de Hoare afirma que si `P` es verdadero antes de una iteración del ciclo, entonces seguirá siendo cierto después, por lo que dicha condición`P` se conoce como [invariante del ciclo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant). Para probar la condición posterior del bucle, debe establecer (1) que `P` es verdadera antes de la primera iteración del bucle, y (2) que`P` es preservada por el cuerpo del bucle.

La invariante necesaria para el bucle en su ejemplo es `sum = n + (n-1) + ... + (cont + 1)`, es decir, la suma de los números de `cont + 1` a`n`. En general, no hay una forma sistemática de encontrar el bucle correcto que se usa invariablemente; tienes que usar tu comprensión del algoritmo y tu intuición / experiencia para crear uno tú mismo.

---

Esto es suficiente para mostrar que * si * el ciclo termina, entonces se cumplirá su condición posterior; También debe establecer que el bucle * termina *. La técnica que debe aplicar aquí es encontrar una [variante de bucle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_variant); esto suele ser una cantidad entera que (1) disminuye en cada iteración del ciclo, y (2) hace que el ciclo finalice cuando la cantidad llega a cero.

En su ejemplo, `cont` es una variante de bucle, porque el bucle disminuye`cont: = cont-1`, y la condición del bucle termina el bucle cuando `cont` llega a cero. En general, como encontrar una invariante útil, no existe un procedimiento sistemático que encuentre una variante en todos los casos, pero puede comenzar mirando la condición del bucle para ver qué variables determinan cuándo termina el bucle.

Answer (score 1):

A continuación le muestro 2 imágenes con el desarrollo del ejercicio planteado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los invito a editar esta publicación para eliminar las imágenes y agregar el texto, espero que le haya sido útil.